# Console.log is not working in Qunit tests with grunt server

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, qunit

I am creating Qunit tests which are running on grunt server. In the test when I am trying to use "console.log" to log some output to the console, it is not printing anything in the console.
Currently I am able to use only OK to perform the assertions.

Please give your inputs.

Comment: did u try `QUnit.log()`?? http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.log/

Comment: I tried but it is not working in my script..

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the qunit task in grunt, you need to start the task with **--debug** (i.e. **grunt test --debug**). You will then see phantom logs printing out your console logs in the following format:

> [D] ["phantomjs","console","MIXPANEL PEOPLE REQUEST (QUEUED, PENDING
>   IDENTIFY):"]

[See documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit)

Comment: Thanks - but that sure does create a lot of very noisy output. Still, better than no logs at all.